# Sum of cubes of two rational but not of two integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there an integer which is the sum of the cubes of two rational numbers, but not the sum of the cubes of two integers?

This is not possible if we consider cubes in place of squares (Davenport-Cassels theorem, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527748), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582188/)), but what about my situation? Notice that $7$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282951/not-the-sum-of-the-squares-of-two-rational-numbers), is not the sum of the cubes of two rational numbers, but every rational number is the sum of the cubes of three rational numbers.

Comment: *cubes of two integers* do the integers have to be positive?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire : I think negative integers / rational are allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is any integer then $n^3 \equiv -1,0,1 \pmod 9$.  Hence if $a,b$ are any integers:

$$a^3 + b^3 \equiv -2,-1,0,1,2 \pmod 9$$
Conversely if any integer $k  \equiv 3,4,5,6 \pmod 9$, it cannot be a sum of two cubes of integers. Searching among small integers meeting this condition, I found:

$$\Big(\frac{2}{3}\Big)^3 + \Big(\frac{7}{3}\Big)^3 = 13$$

Answer (score 2):

$$(\frac{17}{21})^3+(\frac{37}{21})^3=6$$ which is neither the sum nor the difference ot two integer-cubes.

Comment: This looks nice, but why does $6 = a^3+b^3 = a^3 - (-b)^3$ have no solution in the integers?

Comment: The smallest possible difference (if some cube with absolute value $8$ or more is included), is $7$

Comment: Thanks. How did you find this answer? By using a computer,looking for rational cubes giving $6$ as a sum? (Just our of curiosity)

Comment: Of course with a computer : I searched for some solutions with PARI/GP and noticed that $6$ is a suitable integer. I used just brute force :)

Comment: $x^3+y^3=6$ was discussed at an earlier m.se question, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287983/sum-of-cubes-of-two-rationals – the $17,37,21$ solution given here is due to Dudeney, several decades before the invention of computers, and a nice derivation is given in a paragraph in J. H. E. Cohn, The $\pounds450$ Question, Mathematics Magazine Vol. 73, No. 3 (Jun., 2000), pp. 220-226 (7 pages), https://www.jstor.org/stable/2691526